# Is it true that bounded metric can never be induced by norm.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space where, $d$ is metric on $X$.

We know that metric space $X$ is called bounded if there exists some number $r$, such that $d(x,y) ≤ r$ for all $x$and $y$ in $X$.

I want to know is it true that a bounded metric doesn't satisfy homogeneity condition of norm. And thus could we conclude that bounded metric $d$ defined on metric space $X$ can never be induced by any norm.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm (of a real vector space), and $\|v\|=r$ then for every $n\in\Bbb N$ we have $\|n\cdot v-0\|=\|n\cdot v\|=n\cdot r$.

It follows that $\|\cdot\|$ cannot be bounded.

Comment: karagia Thanks for the answer. This mean my observation is correct. Am i right sir?

Comment: Yes. (Also, "Asaf" is my given name, and I wasn't knighted by the queen, so "sir" is unnecessary)

Comment: I have written there full name but i don't know why it didn't come full name. I am sorry for that. Thanks again. :)

Comment: @MinimusHeximus  Oh yes I had observed this. Thanks :)